# Rails update params conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given an update action in controller as:

```
def update_all_item_locations
    @item.item_locations.update_all(
      pricesell: params[:pricesell],
      pricebuy: params[:pricebuy],
      purchased: params[:purchased],
      sold: params[:sold],

    )
  end
```

Is it possible to execute the update only for passed params like params[:pricesell] that are not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can use `delete_if` on the params, something like this:

```
def update_all_item_locations
  whitelisted_params = params.permit(:pricesell, :pricebuy, :purchased, :sold)
  cleaned_params = whitelisted_params.delete_if { |_k, v| v.blank? }
  @item.item_locations.update_all cleaned_params
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is checking if it's null item.item_locations.pricesell not the passed params[:pricesell] right? Perhaps I wasn't clear in the question but I was meaning to check if the passed param is null..

Comment: This individually checks if each of the whitelisted parameter keys has a blank value. If one of them does it will be removed from the cleaned params. Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do either:

```
def update_all_item_locations
  @item.item_locations.update_all(
    params.slice(:pricesell, :pricebuy, :purchased, :solid).permit!
  )
end
```

or...

```
def update_all_item_locations
  @item.item_locations.update_all(
    {
      pricesell: params[:pricesell],
      pricebuy: params[:pricebuy],
      purchased: params[:purchased],
      sold: params[:sold]
    }.compact
  )
end
```

- See [`slice`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-slice) docs.
- See [`compact`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/compact) docs.